# Android canvas.drawText using paint display bad color

Tags: java, android

it's my first question so I hope to fully respect the chart!

I'm using API 19. I display texts on a specific fragment and users can select 2 colors:
The stroke color and the text color.
I draw coloured text as below:

```
// Prepare to draw stroke text
paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
paint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
paint.setStrokeMiter(10);
// Set stroke color
paint.setColor(parseColor(customStrokeColor));
paint.setStrokeWidth(strokeSize);
// Draw Stroke text
canvas.drawText(text, x, y, paint);
// Fill text with text color
paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
paint.setColor(parseColor(customTextColor));
canvas.drawText(text, x, y, paint);
```

And I have an issue with a specific couple of color (more than 1000 couples were tested).
In fact, if I'm using "#FFCC00" as text color and "#FFFFFF" as stroke color I got that bad display (yellow display is "#FFFF00"): 
[Bottom text of the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pUS3i.png)

But if I'm using "#FFCC00" as text color and "#000000" as stroke color I got the good colors [Top text of the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pUS3i.png)

I really need help to understand why and fix it !
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is not really a problem and is working as intended.

#FFFFFF is as white as you can get and #000000 is black. Thus if you set the stroke color to be white, you will have that ugly white outlining and if you set it to black it will have the nice looking black outlining.

Comment: My problem is not about the stroke color but the yellow one inside. I ask for #FFCC00 and the display is #FFFF00 only if stroke color is white..

Comment: @TristanN. I had another look and in both pictures the inside colors are the same. It is the outlining that causes the big difference in perception.

Comment: i change my picture to be more explicit, but if in case it's just a visual effect it is possible to reduce it ?